# What are marginal and conditional errors in a GLMM?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, error, glmm

I'm modifying my ecology paper according to what the reviewers suggested but I have an issue with one statistical-related question.
I ran a GLMM in lme4 on R to model the presence/absence of a certain plant. One reviewer is asking me to report the marginal and conditional error explained by the fixed and random effects. What does that mean and how can I extract them?

Comment: I've never heard of marginal or conditional *errors*. Are you sure they are not asking for marginal and conditional *estimates* ??

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that there has been a misunderstanding or a typo.

In GLMMs the fixed effects estimate are conditional on the random effects. That is, the estimates apply to units in the same subject/cluster/group. They cannot be interpreted as an average over all subjects/clusters/groups. The latter would be *marginal* estimates, while the former are *conditional*.

In R, the GLMMadaptive package can produce both, so this is one approach you can take. Another approach is to fit a generalised estimating equations (GEE) model, which will produce marginal estimates.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, or if not please let us know why so that it can be improved.